# matplotlib.image.imread(): Some images are integers while some others are floats

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I am trying a script that works with images in python.
The first image was working and the second one did not work at all.

The script was

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
image = mpimg.imread('test.jpg')
# Grab the x and y size and make a copy of the image
ysize = image.shape[0]
xsize = image.shape[1]
color_select = np.copy(image)

# Define color selection criteria
###### MODIFY THESE VARIABLES TO MAKE YOUR COLOR SELECTION
red_threshold = 200
green_threshold = 200
blue_threshold = 200
######

rgb_threshold = [red_threshold, green_threshold, blue_threshold]

# Do a boolean or with the "|" character to identify
# pixels below the thresholds
thresholds = (image[:,:,0] < rgb_threshold[0]) \
            | (image[:,:,1] < rgb_threshold[1]) \
            | (image[:,:,2] < rgb_threshold[2])
color_select[thresholds] = [0,0,0]
plt.imshow(color_select)
```

Then I discovered the reason why the second image did not work

```
print("Red channel - Min:", np.min(image[:,:,0]), "Max:", np.max(image[:,:,0]))
print("Green channel - Min:", np.min(image[:,:,1]), "Max:", np.max(image[:,:,1]))
print("Blue channel - Min:", np.min(image[:,:,2]), "Max:", np.max(image[:,:,2]))
```

For the first image

```
Red channel - Min: 0 Max: 255
Green channel - Min: 10 Max: 255
Blue channel - Min: 0 Max: 255
```

For the second image that did not work

```
Red channel - Min: 0.0 Max: 1.0
Green channel - Min: 0.0 Max: 1.0
Blue channel - Min: 0.0 Max: 1.0
```

Can someone explain to me the basics of why some images use 0-255 and other 0.0 to 1.0?

Comment: since this problem involves matplotlib, you should have tagged that (and python!). and you should present those files. so far, your question does not constitute a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are many factors, and discussions of historic practices and influences are not well suited to StackOverflow, but here are my thoughts. I'm sure I have omitted plenty.

For many years camera sensors were 8-bit, producing images in range 0..255 for each sample. Then manufacturers started producing 10-bit sensors, with higher dynamic range 0..1023. Then 12-bit, then 14-bit so the range has increased.

Standard JPEG is only 8-bit capable. PNG is only capable of 8/16-bit at the higher end and still only integer. TIFF and EXR are capable of 32/64-bit at the higher end, but crucially also floating point.

Many early image processing algorithms were/are coded to expect 8-bit samples, e.g. `pixel = 255 - pixel` for image inversion. Of course, that breaks when your data are in the range 0..65535.

Then machine learning came along and it's more sensible to use a range of 0..1 and floats for everything, so inversion is `pixel = 1 - pixel` works if the data are 16-bit floats, 32-bit floats or 64-bit floats.